# removal of admin-ui tabs in products for virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I want to remove product status and product dimension  tab for products in virtuemart 2

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Check the file `'product_edit.php'`

```
administrator\components\com_virtuemart\views\product\tmpl\product_edit.php
```

And Simply comment the not required tabs

```
    $tabarray = array();
    $tabarray['information'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_PRODUCT_INFO_LBL';
    $tabarray['description'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_DESCRIPTION';
   // $tabarray['status'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_PRODUCT_STATUS_LBL';
   // $tabarray['dimensions'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_PRODUCT_DIM_WEIGHT_LBL';
    $tabarray['images'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_PRODUCT_IMAGES_LBL';
    $tabarray['custom'] = 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_FORM_PRODUCT_CUSTOM_TAB';
```

Hope it works..

Comment: can you help me with one more doubt,

Comment: the product price  is not added to cart when user is logged in otherwise it is added

Comment: Is that price is set for some shopper group based ? Then check the users default Shopper group and price condition.